# Hyper-v Ubuntu virtual machine can no longer talk to host

Tags: hyper-v, network-share, windows-10

I am running Windows 10 and hyper-v. I have an Ubuntu VM as a guest vm. I share files to and from the ubuntu machine via a share. \192.168.1.165\share . Everything was working fine until about a week ago when my Windows 10 box could no longer navigate to the share.

My Windows 10 VM cannot ping the Ubuntu box. Ubuntu cannot ping the Windows 10 VM. Both of them can get on the internet and both can ping the router.  Non-host machines on the network can ping Ubuntu, just not the host. I have tried turning off the firewall on the Windows machine, that did not help. I did not make any configuration changes, but all of a sudden they can't see one another.

The guest Ubuntu VM is using "New Virtual Switch" which is "External network" and pointing at the physical network connection of the PC. "Allow management operating system to shre this network adapter" is checked.

Any ideas what to check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Ish. I just reset all my network settings on windows using this guide : http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-reset-all-your-windows-10-network-adapters-just-6-clicks , then recreated the Virtual Switch using "External network", checking "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter", NOT CHECKING "Enable virtual LAN identification for management operating system". I then assigned this switch to my Ubuntu VM.

You probably would not want to do this in a production environment, but for home PC stuff, worked fine.